# javaFX webView showing inaccurate rendering

Tags: javafx, webview

Here are 2 screenshots so you can understand what am talking about ,

this example shows the rendering of ( www.google.com ) in my app and on chrome so you can see the differences.

- [My App Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGqAf.png)
- [Chrome regular Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/152Hp.png)

As you can see , the rendering inside my App is not as ( responsive ) as it is on chrome.

it seems that only ( google.com ) looks this weird , i have tested wikipedia and facebook , Youtube also , they all rendered perfectly.

this the Code I have written if it helps :

```
 @Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    webBoot = new WebView();

    final WebEngine webEngine = webBoot.getEngine();

    webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");
    borderPane.setCenter(webBoot);



}
```

Comment: I've noticed that behavior as well. I've also found that if you alter the [user agent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#userAgentProperty()) to mimic Chrome (or Firefox, maybe others) it will render "normally". I'm not sure of the portability/maintainability of doing that though.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you , your response have actually fixed my problem